# Possible to Store Two Schemas under same partition in Parquet in pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, parquet, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes with different schemas lets say transaction record of merchant dataframe and customer dataframe. I am using PartionBy for writing to partition the df of merchant by year,month and day. Is it possible to store the customer df under same partition?

Thanks.

Comment: Parquet does support schema evolution and schema merging. Have you looked at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging ?

Comment: Yep I looked at it. I used append mode to allow writing to same partitions. So now I have year=2017/month=Jan/day=27 -> customer.parquet and merchant.parquet.          How would I then load customer data of year 2017 ?

Comment: i used mergedSchema = true option but didnt helped. Thanks for the link.